# How do I send an email when users update their email address?

Tags: 8, emails

If users update their email address, an email should be sent to the old and new email addresses to confirm the transaction.

How can I achieve this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a HOOK_user_presave method in your custom module.

Example:

```
function mymodule_user_presave(\Drupal\user\UserInterface $user) {
    if ( !($user->isNew()) ) {
        //check if the value in the db is different to the value in $user
        if ($user->original->getEmail() == $user->getEmail()) {
            // send email
        }
    }
}
```